# What is simplest way to build chat application using Firebase and Flutter

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to **structure data** for chat application in firebase:
that data I want to fetch on is :
1.user is online.
2.messages.
3.read receipt.

Answer (score 1):

Fireship.io has a very good tutorial on it. https://fireship.io/lessons/build-group-chat-with-firestore/ The way they're doing it is very cost efficient.

Comment: op specifically asked for flutter.